# AS ABAP 7.52 SP01 developer edition: DBACOCKPIT can not login to database

Tags: abap

I am using AS ABAP 7.52 SP01, developer edition. I would like to change some DB settings but DBACOCKPIT can not login to the database. I tried all provided DB users, but none seems to work.

Does anybody know why?

[image: DBA Cockpit]

[image: DB Connection]

regards,

Umar Abdullah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working on 7.51 SP02 also. You need to create new connection then test it.

[image: new connection]